# Throwing JavaScript application into <div> ?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm using a JavaScript application called photobooth shown here: [PhotoBooth](http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/)
and I'm using a face detection script an excerpt seen here: [face detection](https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js/issues/9)

To use it you have to specify the the element ID, And I cannot figure out for the life of me what the element ID would be of the JavaScript app, So could I throw the entire thing in Div headers and give it an ID, or somebody help me decode their source and figure out what the canvas layer is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't put the javascript in a div.  The script expects you to identify a div for it to install itself into.

Just put a div on the page like:

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

Then in the javascript:

```
// with jQuery
$("#example").photobooth();

// or, standalone example without jQuery
var myPhotobooth = new Photobooth(document.getElementById( "example"));
```

... and follow the docs.

I just this and it works, but note that if you're specifying an existing element, it must have dimensions of at least 200x200 px, or Photobooth will error.

Comment: here is another example of the face detection script, and it looks like its wanting you to specify a canvas, but I do not know the canvas ID 
http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/sample_haar_face.html